# Is there a function which can make my code read more than one row of CSV file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

```
from pandas import *


dictionary = pandas.read_csv("/Users/vijay/Downloads/England1 postcodes.csv", index_col=1).T.to_dict()

print(dictionary)
```

The code is only giving information of one row and all the info for Columns.
What do I do, so it will give me more than one row of information and information for 3 columns?

Comment: Is it printing the last line? It might just be iterating one line at a time.

Comment: Please post part of the csv so we can test.

Comment: This question doesn't have anything to do with tkinter.

Comment: Have you tried to do the same without transposing?